# Schedular Error Invalid callback

Tags: cron, crontab, schedule

I have added a one schedule task for reindexing. I have used the same code given [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208320/38685). But whenever I added this module in scheduler it gives error like

> Invalid callback: Model for Vendorname_Indexer/cron::run does not
>   exist

I have tried different variations also like without vendorname but its not working. I am using aoe_schedular to added this.

Please let me know the correct  method to add a schedular in Run model tab.